# Symfony 4.1: How to use Dependency Injection in UnitTest (Swift_Mailer)

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, phpunit, swiftmailer, symfony4

In my Symfony4.1-project i am trying to test a method, which should send mails using SwiftMailer, via a unit test.

My test class looks like this

```
namespace App\Tests;

use App\Controller\UserImageValidationController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Tests\TestCase;

class UserImageValidationControllerTest extends TestCase
{

    private $mailer = null;
    public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $testmySwiftMailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $testmySwiftMailer;
    }

    public function testMail()
    {
        $controller = new UserImageValidationController();

        $controller->notifyOfMissingImage(
            'a',
            'b',
            'c',
            'd',
            $this->mailer
        );
    }
}
```

The problem is, that when i run `./bin/phpunit` i get an exception saying

> Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function App\Tests\UserImageValidationControllerTest::__construct(), 0 [...] and exactly 1 expected [...]

It seemes like in the test environment DI isn't working.

So i added

```
bind:
    $testmySwiftMailer: '@swiftmailer.mailer.default'
```

To my *config/services_test.yaml* but i still got the same error.
I also added `autowiring: true` to that file (just to try it) and it also doesn't work.
Also, i tried with a service-alias, like it states in the file's comments: still no success.

How do i get the swiftmailer injected into my test case constructor?

Comment: The docs are pretty clear that the basic test case has no knowledge of the Symfony container.  And certainly the php new operator is container ignorant.  More importantly, ask yourself why you feel the need to test the Swift_Mailer class?  It already has a bunch of tests for it.  You might consider mocking it.

Comment: @Cerad i don't want to test the Swift_Mailer but i really want to send the mail during my test using the Swift_Mailer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tests are not part of the container and don't act as services so your solution is not valid. Extend `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase` and do that instead (making sure your service is public first):

```php
protected function setUp()
{
    static::bootKernel();

    $this->mailer = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('mailer');
}

protected function tearDown()
{
    $this->mailer = null;
}
```

Comment: In this case, you should define the service or its alias as public.

Comment: Not in symfony 4

Comment: Why not? It doesn't work in Symfony 4.2 without defining of the alias

Comment: Very well explained here https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-1-simpler-service-testing

Comment: The mocking of a service doesn't work without to define the service or its alias as public

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will not work for services that are not defined as public. However after Symfony 4.1, to be able to access private services while on testing, you need to get the service from a special testing container.

From the Symfony documentation:

> tests based on `WebTestCase` and `KernelTestCase` now access to a special container via the `static::$container` property that allows fetching non-removed private services

example:

```php
namespace App\Tests;

use App\Controller\UserImageValidationController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class UserImageValidationControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    private $mailer = null;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();

        // gets the special container that allows fetching private services
        $container = self::$container;

        $this->mailer = $container->get('mailer');
    }

    public function testMail()
    {
        $controller = new UserImageValidationController();

        $controller->notifyOfMissingImage(
            'a',
            'b',
            'c',
            'd',
            $this->mailer
        );
    }
}
```